# Android - View background changes color automatically

Tags: android, view, background-color

I don't know if anyone else has faced this problem, but one of the views in my app changes its colour to grey automatically sometimes. The colour I have set is white, But I dont know how this is happening. I have checked my code properly, and I have not set a colour change anywhere.

Comment: send your code and XML layout.

Comment: post some code. do you have a scroll container there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set `android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" on your`ListView`.

Comment: Thanks. :) This seems to work. But why does this happen?

Comment: you can have a look here http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html. it is basically an rendering optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You might be leaking memory, check your logcat while debugging and see if there are any messages related to heap size or track how many times is the gc being called? What kind view is it?

EDIT: 
if its a listview try @Ovidiu's answer..